# How to integrate SVN in JDeveloper 11.1.1.4.0

Tags: svn, jdeveloper, visualsvn-server

I need to add my project to SVN using jdeveloper 11.1.1.4.0, but the IDE crashes when trying to connect to the repository.

The login credentials are correct, I can access via browser.

Comment: does it “crash” or does it show an error? what error do you see?

Comment: JDeveloper hangs and I need to kill the process

Comment: If JDeveloper *hangs* then it make sense to contact its support for assistance since now this looks like a bug in JDeveloper.